# Docker - dist file disappeared after running docker-compose up -d

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, docker, nestjs

I have a nestJS application using Dockerfile to build

backend/Dockerfile

```
FROM node:18-alpine

# Reuse the old commits if dependencies are not changed
ADD package.json /tmp/package.json
RUN cd /tmp && npm install
RUN mkdir -p /app && cp -a /tmp/node_modules /app

WORKDIR /app
COPY . .

RUN npm run build // dist file is supposed to be generated in this step

CMD [ "npm", "run", "dev" ]
```

I use Docker Compose for bootstrap my entire applications
docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.5'

services:
  backend:
    build: 
      context: ./backend
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    container_name: backend
    ports: 
      - '3001:3001'
    volumes:
      - ./backend:/app
    depends_on:
      - database

  database:
    image: mongo:6.0
    container_name: mongodb
    restart: always
    ports:
      - '27017:27017'
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: 'XXX'
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: '1234'
```

However when I run `docker-compose up -d`, the dist file is not generated in the docker container. Below is the result of `docker logs -f backend`

```
> nest start --watch -b swc

>  SWC  Running...
Bindings not found.
Bindings not found.
Bindings not found.
Bindings not found.
Bindings not found.
Bindings not found.
Bindings not found.
Bindings not found.
Bindings not found.
Bindings not found.
Bindings not found.
Bindings not found.
Bindings not found.
Bindings not found.
Bindings not found.
Bindings not found.
Bindings not found.
Bindings not found.
Bindings not found.
Bindings not found.
Failed to compile 20 files with swc.
Watching for file changes.
Error: Cannot find module '/app/dist/main'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1134:15)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:975:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:128:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:28:49
```

I tried to run `npm run build` locally to manually build a `dist` file to sync to the container, but whenever I run `docker-compose up -d` it just disappeared.

How to fix it?

**Update 1**
I tried to run `docker exec -it backend sh`, and run `npm run build`, a `dist` is created. However when I run `npm run dev`, the `dist` file disappeared and the exact error shown

package.json

```
  "scripts": {
    "build": "nest build",
    "dev": "nest start --watch -b swc",
    ...
  },
```

Comment: Are you trying to run the dev environment in the docker environment or do you attempt to use the `--watch` in a production environment?

Comment: The `volumes:` block hides everything in the image; I'd recommend deleting it.  You can use a live-reloading server on the host without Docker for day-to-day development, even if your dependencies run in containers and you're eventually going to deploy via a container.

Comment: @DavidMaze I have a frontend and database container, and I need live reloading for each of them

Comment: Can you open two terminal windows and `npm run dev` in each of them (without Docker)?  You can `docker-compose up -d database` to get the components that aren't the code you're working on in containers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved it by

1. `docker exec -it backend sh`
2. `npm install`

No idea why it solves the issue

Answer (score 0):

Use `node dist/main` instead of `nest start ...`.

`nest start` **compiles** and runs an application, this should not be used in Docker container.